# My app runs on docker but gets a JDBC error?

Tags: docker, containers

i am getting the following:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I've created the image for my application, downloaded the needed images from docker hub.
Is there anything else should i do?
For example with the container putting in them?

Comment: Is your app a simple java app, or do you launch an app+a database from a docker compose file, for example ? Do you have a rdms installed and functionning ?

Comment: I am launching my app + two databases and Kafka. Yes i have them both images downloaded and it worked when i ran locally. when i builded as an image and put in container network with the others - it shows this message

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to access urls with `localhost` as the host.

Accessing `localhost` or 127.0.0.1 from a container does not call the host, but the container itself. If you have apps contacting other apps on a docker network, you should use the container name as a host, or a value that you will pass to the container with the `--hostname` option. For this to work, you **have to** use a user defined docker network, not the default network. If you use Docker compose, that is managed for you.

Comment: okay, i will try changing the String connection names with the container name.
another thing - when deployed and run, does this affects the mapped endpoints?

Comment: Which mapped endpoints ? Your questions are very unclear, we do not have your context and thus we cannot easily answer without making lots of assumptions...

Comment: So, my app was working with Spring Boot and created a REST API with endpoints getting information from the two databases(localhost:port). Now I have to move everything to docker packed up and that's the problem occurs

Comment: Okay. So, your app and your databases are now in docker ? Do you use docker compose ? If not, have you created a network and attached your containers to this network?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When I build an image from the dockerfile and then compose the network with the app + openjdk it gets the message from above.

Comment: Okay. Then, as I tried to say in my answer, you shouldn't use `localhost` on your URL to connect to the database but use the container name/hostname you gave to the database containers on the network.

Comment: so my container name is mysql and it should be `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://demo/mysql-db:3306/users_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp
`
demo is the name of the network

Comment: does this affects the Kafka BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG also?

Comment: I am changing my connection url strings and when i build the .jar via maven it gets an error.... seems to be stuck with this.

Comment: Connection string should be `jdbc:mysql://<insert the container name here>:<insert the container port here>/<insert the rest of the math here>`

Comment: it doesn't works again, mate.
Will try to find a solution of this.